# How to Get results from multiple tables using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am working on autocomplete textbox. In this user can type their city name and from this input i want to search records from database table and display related combination list of city name, state name and country name.

How can i get this details using LINQ.

I have my table structure as below,

**Country**
Countryid PK
CountryName

**State**
Stateid PK
StateName
Countryid FK

**City**
Cityid PK
CityName
Stateid FK

I want to get result on autocomplete textbox.

E.g if user writes san
he will get list of city name contains san

like San Francisco, California, United States of America.

How can i write LINQ query to get this result.

Comment: Is this LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities (Entity Framework)? It can't be both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from c in dataContext.City
            where c.Contains(keyword)
            select c.CityName + ", " + c.State.StateName+ ", "+ c.State.Country.CountryName;
```

Comment: @JohnSaunders how about now, John?

Answer (score 1):

Using linq-to-sql:

```
var q = from c in context.cities
select c.CityName + ", " + c.State.StateName + ", " + c.State.Country.CountryName
where CityName.StartsWith(typed);
```

This will give an IEnumerable with the suggestions that matches the typed characters.

Comment: You may want to try profiling the difference between putting the where clause at the end and placing it before the select clause. With LINQ to Objects, your syntax would be sub-optimal, but it is possible that the LINQ provider and/or database engine will optimize the extra sub-select away.

Comment: @Jim Wooley: If this is linq-to-sql the DB engine will take care of that. If it was linq-to-objects the order of where vs. select makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant:

```
var matches = cities.Where(c => c.CityName.Contains(substr))
                    .Select(a => String.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
                                        a.CityName, 
                                        a.State.StateName, 
                                        a.State.Country.CountryName 
                           ));
```